# SQL Query pulling extra data

Tags: sql, api, soap, soapui

I am using this query in SOAPUI against our SOAP API.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:del="http://tempuri.org/Deltek.Vision.WebServiceAPI.Server/DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <del:GetProjectsByQuery>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <del:ConnInfoXML><![CDATA[<VisionConnInfo> 
              <databaseDescription>Description</databaseDescription> 
              <userName>USERNAME</userName>
              <userPassword>PASSWORD</userPassword>
              <integratedSecurity>Y</integratedSecurity> 
            </VisionConnInfo>]]></del:ConnInfoXML>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <del:Query>SELECT WBS1,Name,Principal FROM PR WHERE PR.WBS1='H15032.00'</del:Query>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <del:RecordDetail>'Project'</del:RecordDetail>
      </del:GetProjectsByQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The request goes through and gives me a response, however it gives me additional fields also. I just want to pull the column specified in query itself like WBS1, Name, and Principal fields only.

```
<WBS1>H15032.00</WBS1> 
<Name>Name</Name> 
<Principal>Principal Name</Principal>
<custLetterofIntent>Y</custLetterofIntent>
<custIssued>2015-06-03T00:00:00.000</c‌​ustIssued>
<CreateUser>KGOODENOW</CreateUser>
<CreateDate>2015-06-03T15:51:20.913</‌​CreateDate>
<ModUser>KGOODENOW</ModUser>
<ModDate>2015-06-03T15:52:29.227</ModDate>‌​
<CustContractStatus>LOI</CustContractStatus>
</ROW>
</Projects_ConsultantAgreements‌​>
</REC>
</RECS>]]>
</GetProjectsByQueryResult>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by additional data? please post the expected results and the results you get.

Comment: My expected results would be, <WBS1>H15032.00</WBS1> <Name>Name</Name> <Principal>Principal Name</Principal> Instead I am getting all of that plus every other field in the table, memo, charge type etc.

Comment: Quite a interesting question +1 for you. I am not sure why this is happening.  You are using wsdl to read the fields?

Comment: That is correct, WSDL is being  used. It's like it's overlooking my SELECT and just pulling my FROM and WHERE

Comment: and your output comes in soap Envelope? Can you show little bit more code other than query only. Edit your question to add code

Comment: I edited it to show my entire request code, changed the username and password and description obviously.